# Mocking Stripe::Charge - RSpec says that it does not implement :retrieve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying to mock `Stripe::Charge.retrieve` in some of my tests, but am getting the error:

```
Failure/Error: allow_any_instance_of(Stripe::Charge).to receive(:retrieve)
       Stripe::Charge does not implement #retrieve
```

I am guessing the Stripe API does some sort of reflection to generate this method. Is there a way to mock this method? Or maybe a way to turn off the RSpec feature that verifies that mocked methods exist for specific tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Stripe::Charge.retrieve`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#retrieve_charge) is a class method, but you're trying to mock it like an instance method. The biggest tip-off here is that the method's called "retrieve" - you're trying to get a `Stripe::Charge` object, and it's more idiomatic in Ruby to use a class method for that. Rspec's error isn't very useful; it would be more accurate if it said "Instances of `Stripe::Charge` do not implement #retrieve".

The good news is you can mock this in Rspec quite straightforwardly:

```
allow(Stripe::Charge).to receive(:retrieve)
```

---

Here's a short example demonstrating this, taken from a Rails project that includes the Stripe gem and rspec-rails. First, a mostly-empty Payment model:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_stripe_charge(payment_ref)
    Stripe::Charge.retrieve(payment_ref)
  end
end
```

And now a `spec/models/payment_spec.rb` to demonstrate the mocking:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Payment, type: :model do
  it "Allows retrieval of a payment" do
    allow(Stripe::Charge).to receive(:retrieve).and_return("Avocados") # A mock object would be more useful here.

    payment = Payment.new
    expect(payment.get_stripe_charge("whatever")).to eql("Avocados")
  end
end
```